# Argument list too long - Unix

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sh

This scripts will sort the files by date then move the first 2500 files to another directory.
When I run below scripts, system prompt out Argument list too long msg. Anyone can help me enhance the scripts ? Thanks

```
NUM_OF_FILES=2500
FROM_DIRECTORY=/apps/data01/RAID/RC/MD/IN_MSC/ERC/in
DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=/apps/data01/RAID/RC/MD/IN_MSC/ERC/in_load

if [ ! -d $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY ]  
        then  
                echo "unused_file directory does not exist!"  
        mkdir $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY   
        echo "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY directory created!"  
else   
        echo "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY exist!"    
fi  


echo "Moving $NUM_OF_FILES oldest files to $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY directory"  

ls -tr  $FROM_DIRECTORY/MSCERC*.Z|head -$NUM_OF_FILES |
    xargs -i sh -c "mv {} $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

Comment: are you trying to move only the first 2500 files?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say, but I assume this is where the problem occurs:

```
ls -tr  $FROM_DIRECTORY/MSCERC*.Z|head -2500 | \
    xargs -i sh -c "mv {} $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

(You can verify it by adding "set -x" to the top of your script.)

The problem is that the kernel has a fixed maximum size of the total length of the command line given to a new process, and your exceeding that in the `ls` command. You can work around it by not using globbing and instead using `grep`:

```
ls -tr  $FROM_DIRECTORY/ | grep '/MSCERC\*\.Z$' |head -2500 | \
    xargs -i sh -c "mv {} $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

(`grep` uses regular expressions instead of globs, so the pattern looks a little bit different.)

Comment: same error -  Argument list too long msg. Fyi $FROM_DIRECTORY contain > 200k files.

Comment: That's weird. If you could provide output from running with "set -x", we could be sure, but my best guess at this point is that either you added an asterisk to the ls command, or something goes wrong with xargs. If the latter, add -n10 to the xargs options.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
ls -tr  $FROM_DIRECTORY/MSCERC*.Z|head -2500 | \
    xargs -i sh -c "mv {} $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

do something like the following:

```
find "$FROM_DIRECTORY" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'MSCERC*.Z' -printf '%p\t%T@\n' | sort -k2,2 -r | cut -f1 | head -$NUM_OF_FILES | xargs mv -t "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

This uses find to create a list of files with modification timestamps, sorts by the timestamp, then removes the unneeded field before passing the output to `head` and `xargs`

**EDIT**

Another variant, should work with non GNU utils

```
find "$FROM_DIRECTORY" -type f -name 'MSCERC*.Z' -printf '%p\t%T@' |sort -k 2,2 -r | cut -f1 | head -$NUM_OF_FILES | xargs -i mv \{\} "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"
```

Comment: @user: There's really no need for you to acknowledge each answer

Comment: I run the command , it didnt work. I hv changed the scripts as this find $FROM_DIRECTORY/ -name  'MSCERC*.Z' | head -2500 | xargs -i sh -c  "mv {} $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY" . It succeffuly moved the files to destinaton directory. My questions is, how to order the files by date so the system will pick up the first 2500 files?

Comment: @user871695: I've updated my answer, the following should work, also orders files by modification time, as your original `ls` based snippet does.

Comment: This is wat i get                                               find: bad option -maxdepth
Usage: sort [-AbcdfiMmnru] [-T Directory] [-tCharacter] [-y kilobytes] [-o File]
           [-k Keydefinition].. [[+Position1][-Position2]].. [-z recsz] [File]..
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] [-e warn|force|ignore] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] [-e warn|force|ignore] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] [-e warn|force|ignore] d1 d2

Comment: @user871695: The command line I suggested should work for GNU findutils,  what OS (BSD, etc.) are you on? You could drop `-maxdepth` if you don't have any subdirectories under the from directory. also, could you post the output of `find --version` or similar?

Comment: system is HP-UX, this time it gv me bad option -printf. i think the sort command didnt work in my case ..fyi my file timestamp is sumthing like this JUL 31 16:25

Comment: @user871695: Okay, that was useful information, It appears you can't use the HP-UX `find` for this (as it doesn't support formatted output). I suggest you either install the GNU findutils, or try Lars Wirzenius' answer, which should work.

Answer (score 1):

First of create a backup list of the files to be treated. Then read the backup file line-by-line and heal it. For example

```
 #!/bin/bash
 NUM_OF_FILES=2500
 FROM_DIRECTORY=/apps/data01/RAID/RC/MD/IN_MSC/ERC/in
 DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=/apps/data01/RAID/RC/MD/IN_MSC/ERC/in_load

 if [ ! -d $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY ]  
    then  
            echo "unused_file directory does not exist!"  
    mkdir $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY   
    echo "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY directory created!"  
  else   
    echo "$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY exist!"    
 fi  

 echo "Moving $NUM_OF_FILES oldest files to $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY directory" 

 ls -tr  $FROM_DIRECTORY/MSCERC*.Z|head -2500 > list
 exec 3<list

 while read file <&3
 do
    mv $file $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
 done
```

Comment: Thank for your replied, sry I didnt get what you mean. Im new to unix, what is the functions of heal ?

Comment: user: I've corrected my answer. Thank you for your upvote and satisfaction!

Comment: same error - Argument list too long msg. Fyi $FROM_DIRECTORY contain > 200k files

Comment: I think my solutions is useless - try Hasturkan.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix this would be to change to $FROM_DIRECTORY, so that you can refer the files using (shorter) relative paths.

`cd $FROM_DIRECTORY && 
ls -tr MSCERC*.Z|head -2500 |xargs -i sh -c "mv {}   $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY"`

This is also not entirely fool-proof, if you have too many files that match.

Comment: same error - Argument list too long msg. Fyi $FROM_DIRECTORY contain > 200k files