# sed: Argument list too long

Tags: shell, sed

I have created a script in Unix environment. In the script, I used the `sed` command as shown below to delete some lines from the file. I want to delete a specified set of lines, not necessarily a simple range, from the file, specified by line numbers.

```
sed -i "101d; 102d; ... 4930d;" <file_name>
```

When I execute this it shows the following error:

```
sed: Arg is too long
```

Can you please help to resolve this problem?

Comment: I've added necessary quotation marks to your `sed` command; please verify that this is the command you're using. Are you trying to delete a contiguous range of lines, or some arbitrary list of lines? (The command you show, assuming a reasonable replacement for the `...`, won't delete 4930 lines; it will delete lines up to #4930).

Comment: Can you tell us *exactly* which lines you want to delete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument list too long - Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890632/argument-list-too-long-unix)

Comment: @tripleee: It's not really a duplicate. It's a similar problem, but the solutions aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer based on some of your comments. Please confirm that it still reflects what you're asking.

Comment: Where do you get the line numbers from? If they are generated by a different command, pipe that directly into `sed`, something like: `cmd | sed 's/$/d/' | sed -f - file`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete a contiguous range of lines, you can specify a range of line numbers:

```
sed -i '101,4930d' file
```

If you want to delete some arbitrary set of lines that can't easily be expressed as a range, you can put the commands in a file rather than on the command line, and use `sed -f`.

For example, if `foo.sed` contains:

```
2d
4d
6d
8d
10d
```

then this:

```
sed -i -f foo.sed file
```

will delete lines 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 from `file`.  Putting the commands in a file rather than on the command line avoids limits on command line length.

If there's some pattern to the lines you want to delete, you might consider using a more sophisticated tool such as Awk or Perl.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thompson.. I have one another question. if we use the above command by put the line no in a file then it should also give the same error. Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @sumitvedi: First, I still don't know just what you're trying to do. Please explain exactly which lines you want to delete. Are you deleting lines 1 through 4930? 101 through 4930? Some arbitrary set of lines? Second, no, if the commands are in a file and you use `sed -f` as I explained, you shouldn't get the same error. Incidentally, on my system the error message is "Argument list too long", not "Arg is too long"; please copy-and-paste the exact message.

Comment: Yes.. Themson, I have some arbitrary set of line. which i want to delete

Comment: @sumitvedi: (Just call me Keith.) Then the sed solution I gave you should work. Just replace the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 with the list of lines you want to delete. If there's no useful pattern in the sequence of line numbers, there's not much point in using something more sophisticated than sed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem.

I originally put the giant sed command `sed -i "101d; 102d; ... 4930d;" <file_name>` in a file and tried to execute as a bash script.

To fix - put only the deletion commands in a file and run that file as a sed script. I was able to execute 18,193 deletion commands that had failed to run before.

`sed -i -f to_delete.sed input_file`

to_delete.sed:

`101d;102d;...4930d`

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk ' NR < 101 || NR > 4930 { print } ' input_file
```

Comment: Thanks perreal. But I have some arbitrary set of line. which i want to delete from file by line no.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and awk):

```
cat <<\! >/tmp/a
> 2
> 4
> 6
> 8
> !
seq 10 >/tmp/b
sed 's/$/d/' /tmp/a | sed -f - /tmp/b
1
3
5
7
9
10
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next};FNR in a{next};1' /tmp/{a,b}
1
3
5
7
9
10
```