# Argument list too long when concatenating lots of files in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

This is a command to concatenate multiple same pattern files into one big files. In the folder I have 77k files, and I get `Argument list too long`

Example file names are per minute: `cartreset-2014-05-08-01-12.log`

```
rm -f /tmp/temp.files
ls -1 /var/log/processing/*.log | \
    xargs -n1 basename > /tmp/temp.files
cat /tmp/temp.files | \
    sed -r "s~(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+\.log~cat /var/log/processing/\1* >> /var/log/processing/\1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log~" | \
    uniq | \
    sh
cd /var/log/processing
xargs rm -rf < /tmp/temp.files
rm -f /tmp/temp.files

sh: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

what options do I have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument list too long - Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890632/argument-list-too-long-unix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your full code is:

```
rm -f /tmp/temp.files
ls -1 /var/log/processing/*.log | xargs -n1 basename > /tmp/temp.files
cat /tmp/temp.files | sed -r "s~(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+\.log~cat /var/log/processing/\1* >> /var/log/processing/\1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log~" | uniq | sh
cd /var/log/processing
xargs rm -rf < /tmp/temp.files
rm -f /tmp/temp.files
```

But the problem lies on the `ls -1  /var/log/processing/*.log` part, so I am skipping the rest.

The expansion done by `/var/log/processing/*.log` gives so many results that `ls` itself cannot handle all of them and hence prints the "Argument list too long" message.

You can use a `find` statement like this:

```
find /var/log/processing -name "*.log" -exec basename {} \; > /tmp/temp.files
```

See I am not using ls parsing (read interesting [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: @JanHudec have you checked the full answer in which I indicate it is not recommendable to do so?

Comment: Then why don't you just put the pattern in the loop?!

Comment: I got input file is output file now, I didn't get this earlier.

Comment: You didn't have to remove the for; it is actually most reasonable thing to do in many cases.

Comment: probably because of cat file2 >> file1, but how to avoid these to be the same?

Comment: cat /tmp/temp.files | sed -r "s~(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+\.log~cat ' . $srcFolder . '/\1* >> ' . $dstFolder . '/\1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log~" | uniq | sh;

Comment: @Pentium10 it looks weird, but should make it. As you marked the answer as accepted, I guess your issue is solved. Let me know if it is not!

Answer (score 2):

Parsing output of `ls` is [always wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Anyway, the problem is that the pattern expands to so many files that maximum permissible length of command-line is exceeded. There are two ways to avoid it:

1. Using a `for` loop. Expansion of pattern in a for loop is processed internally by the shell and therefore not limited by the command-line length:

   ```
   for file in /var/log/processing/*.log
   do
       basename "$file"
   done > /tmp/temp.files
   ```

   (yes, output of the loop as a whole can be redirected after the `done` keyword)
   When you are running `xargs` with `-n1`, it is even slightly more efficient to use a loop.
2. Using `find`:

   ```
   find /var/log/processing \
       -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' \
       -printf '%f\n' > /tmp/temp.files
   ```

   the `'%f'` prints just the filename, so it saves you calling the `basename`. The `-maxdepth` is there so the command is actually equivalent to the pattern; if there are no subdirectories, you can skip it. On the other hand if there *are* subdirectories, you may want to use `%P`, which gives you relative paths from the first argument (`/var/log/processing`).

I would probably try to get rid of the temporary file altogether and do the work in one or more loops.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the temp file, you can use bash arrays:

```
cd /var/log/processing

logs=( *.log )
prefixes=( "${logs[@]/-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].log/}" )

date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

printf "%s\n" "${prefixes[@]}" | 
sort -u |
while read -r prefix; do
    cat "$prefix"* >> "$prefix"-"$date".log
done 

printf "%s\n" "${logs[@]}" | xargs rm

cd -
```

Comment: Note that if your line ends with a pipe, you don't need the backslash line continuation.