# Unix - arg list too long

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Using bash 3.2.  Trying to delete some log files older than 7 days...anyways this command works on another server but not on the current one.

Wondering if anyone can fix the syntax for me as I'm no Unix expert:

```
find /export/home1/dir1/dir2/sync/logs/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument list too long - Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890632/argument-list-too-long-unix)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `*` from path of `find`:

```
find /export/home1/dir1/dir2/sync/logs/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

or if you newer `find` version:

```
find /export/home1/dir1/dir2/sync/logs/ -mtime +7 -delete
```

By having `*` in path shell expands to all the available entries in the given directory.

Comment: ty the top one worked, bottom didn't.  It won't let me mark as answer though lol

Comment: When this is a regular job, consider using logrotate to assist you to do it daily...